# 'filenotfound' exception on Android

Tags: java, android

I keep getting a file not found exception even though the path exists. The path is taken from were I originally created the file, so I assume the path is correct. The error happens at the FileInputStream mark below by error.

This is the error: W/System.err? java.io.FileNotFoundException: /file:/storage/emulated/0/footyman/img_1429035461315.jpg: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

```
     public static void addProfilePic(final Uri path,final String imgName) {

        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {
            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(Void... par) {
                String done;

                try {
                    // Retrieve storage account from connection-string.
                    CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.parse(storageConnectionString);

                    // Create the blob client.
                    CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.createCloudBlobClient();

                    // Retrieve reference to a previously created container.
                    CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.getContainerReference("profilepics");

                    // Define the path to a local file.
                    final String filePath = path.toString();
                    Log.i("filepath", filePath);

                    // Create or overwrite the "myimage.jpg" blob with contents from a local file.
                    CloudBlockBlob blob = container.getBlockBlobReference(imgName);
                    File source = new File(path.toString()); // error here
                    blob.upload(new FileInputStream(source.toURI().getPath()), source.length());
                    done = "true";
                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                    // Output the stack trace.
                    done = "false";
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return done;
            }

            protected void onPostExecute(String done) {
                if (done.equals("true")) {
                    Log.i("add pic", "success");
                } else {
                    Log.i("add pic", "failed");

                }
            }
        }.execute();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

/file:/storage/emulated/0/footyman/img_1429035461315.jpg remove the '/file:' so you only use /storage/emulated/0/footyman/img_1429035461315.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Your URI looks malformed and should be like this:

**file:///storage/emulated/0/footyman/img_1429035461315.jpg**

Comment: I tried hard code this uri in but to no the exact same error still appears